# Enable only next seven day in moment-format component

Tags: javascript, ember.js, handlebars.js

In ember i am using component of npm package ember-moment

> {{moment-format date 'dddd DD/MM'}}

How can i enable only next seven days?

Comment: What result you want to achieve, and what do you have now?

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer for this, We can use an option "maxDate" and set it with our maximum date till what we want to show days on cordova-datepicker.

It worked for me.